# Failed to convert value(s) to axis units datetime

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

I am trying to plot a line using, as coordinates, also a datetime variable. But still having the same error. Any help?

I have tried to use a variable as plot coordinate (x axis). The variable is the difference between a specific date and the current day.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2023, 12, 1)

d1 = date.today()

delta = d1 - d0

mm7g = np.array([82.9, 82.8, 82.9])

plt.plot((delta, 35), (mm7g[-1], 78), zorder = 0, color = 'g', linewidth = 0.4, ls = '--')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please, it would help us to help you if you write a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your message (example: "using using, as coordinates").

Comment: How about this: `plt.plot(delta.days, mm7g[-1], marker='o')`. It'll plot the difference in days on the x axis, and the data on the y axis. It does this for only one single point, because your delta is just a single value.

Comment: Thank you. Ii works. This is exactly what I was looking for.